# Getting weirdly formatted NSDictionary value

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

```
var nsarray:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["object":["uid":["age":"26","gender":"male"]]]]

print(nsarray[0]["object"])
```

That is how it looks. I want to get the value "uid", so when it prints it is just "uid". Currently it is printing:

```
"uid":["age":"26","gender":"male"]
```

Comment: That's what it's supposed to print out.

Comment: I want to get the "uid" value. Meaning when it prints it is just "uid". I need the uid as a string.

Comment: So many questions here: **1.** Why is the variable called "nsarray" when in fact it's a Swift `Array`? **2.** Why are you using `NSDictionary`? **2.** Why are you nesting dictionaries in such a complex manner, rather than using simple structs? **3.** What's the exact input you're dealing with? **4.** What's the exact output you desire?

Comment: Not my app, but the app I'm helping out with retrieves data from their back end and this is the format. Also this was typed out in playground to explain the situation. Probably shouldn't of used nsarray as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the "uid" value. Meaning when it prints it is just "uid". "uid" is a placeholder for a unique ID so I won't know what the uid is.

It looks like `"object"` key contains another dictionary, which has exactly one element. To get the first key, call `allKeys` to get keys, convert them to `Array`, and pick the the initial element:

```
let d = nsarray[0]["object"] as! NSDictionary
print(Array(d.allKeys)[0])
```

Comment: Well "uid" is a placeholder for a unique ID so I won't know what the uid is. I need to get the unique ID

Comment: @gooberboobbutt How exactly do you expect us to gues sthat's what you're after? You need to be clearer on exactly what input you have, and what output you desire

Comment: Well @dasblinkenlight got the answer